# Debugging an aar library referenced in Another Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, aar, android-debug

I have an .aar created from the Android sources and I am trying to debug the calls made to it by referencing it in another Android Studio Project(Project Box).But on clicking debugging in the Box project at some point where I am calling the method defined in the aar lib,I am getting "Unfortunately, MyAPP has stopped"

In my build.gradle i have already defined the lib name in the dependencies section

```
{
   compile(name:'myaarlib name',ext:'aar');
}
```

The app works fine in the release mode.How can I Step in step out the source code of the Library by referencing it in my "Box" project.Am I missing any settings?